# Design pattern to extract information from a complex object

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose a class Company that includes a list of Departments. Each department has a list of employees.

Now I want to extract various information from a Company object. For example, I want to extract all of the Male employees. Or extract all of the departments in Canada. Whatever new need that comes up, I want to create a new object to extract this information without having to modify my business object (Company, Department, Employee). I want to respect the open/closed principle.

What would be the best design pattern in this case?

I looked at the visitor pattern. Here is what I found.

1- Visit method returns void. That means my visitor will need to keep all extracted object internally. This means I cannot use the visitor as a singleton.

2- Each visitor needs to know how to loop through the Departments/Employees. It leads to a good amount of duplicated code. I could move that code into an abstract class. I feel the abstract might grow ugly and big.

Comment: you might want to use the iterator design pattern to loop through things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to respect the open/closed principle.

If you want to respect that principle you must decide what is open and what is closed. Being completely open means that you separate the data from the logic. In this case your "objects" are reduced to simple data container with maybe a getter and setter without logic. The logic is then placed somewhere else.
That's the opposite of object-oriented programming, because object-oriented programming brings data and logic together.

So I would design my Company and Department in a way that I can query for objects by defining a criteria. The way a company loops over it's departments and applies the criteria is closed for me. The criteria is the open part.

So that it will look something like this from a client's perspective.

```
List<Employee> employees = company.getEmployees(e -> e.getFristname().startsWith("R"));
```

The classes would then be implemented in this way

**Company**

```
public class Company {

    private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    public Company(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartments(Predicate<Department> departmentPredicate) {
        List<Department> matchingDepartments = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Department department : departments) {
            if (departmentPredicate.test(department)) {
                matchingDepartments.add(department);
            }
        }

        return matchingDepartments;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(Predicate<Employee> predicate) {
        return getEmployees(d -> true, predicate);
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(Predicate<Department> departmentPredicate,
            Predicate<Employee> employeePredicate) {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Department department : departments) {
            if (departmentPredicate.test(department)) {
                List<Employee> employeesOfDepartment = department.getEmployees(employeePredicate);
                employees.addAll(employeesOfDepartment);
            }
        }

        return employees;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void add(Department department) {
        departments.add(department);
    }

}
```

**Department**

```
public class Department {

    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees(Predicate<Employee> predicate) {
        List<Employee> matchingEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            if (predicate.test(employee)) {
                matchingEmployees.add(employee);
            }
        }

        return matchingEmployees;
    }

    public void add(Employee employee) {
        employees.add(employee);
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(employees);
    }

}
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {

    private String fristname;
    private String lastname;

    public Employee(String fristname, String lastname) {
        this.fristname = fristname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFristname() {
        return fristname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [fristname=" + fristname + ", lastname=" + lastname + "]";
    }

}
```

And an example client code might look like this

```
Company company = new Company("Stackoverflow");

Department javaDepartment = new Department("Java");

Employee reneLink = new Employee("René", "Link");
javaDepartment.add(reneLink);

Employee pMartin = new Employee("Martin", "P");
javaDepartment.add(pMartin);

Employee rayTayek = new Employee("Ray", "Tayek");
javaDepartment.add(rayTayek);

company.add(javaDepartment);

List<Employee> employees = company.getEmployees(e -> e.getFristname().startsWith("R"));
System.out.println(employees);
```

**Making it more open**

If you now try to make the classes more "open" you will see where the journey ends.

You might introduce getter for the collections and use streams in the client code. Something like this:

```
Predicate<? super Department> departmentPredicate = d -> true; // just a simple predicate

List<Employee> employees = company.getDepartments().stream()
                                    .filter(departmentPredicate)
                                    .map(Department::getEmployees)
                                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                                    .filter(e -> e.getFristname().startsWith("R"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you can see you will move a lot of iteration logic out of the `Company` and `Department` classes to the client code.

But this also means that the iteration code has to be tested in every client. If you place it in the `Company` and `Department` class you will only need a test there.

I think that the query method shown in the first example above are a fair balance between open and close and they are more readable then the stream example.

But if you want to use the stream api you can still use it inside the query methods.

Comment: Thanks for your time! This is pretty much what I was looking for! When I said Open/closed I meant Closed to modification... but Open to inheritance. Great answer anyway! Thanks